# Mapbox NavigationView UI set Dark Mode with Route Color to Red

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I have implemented latest **Mapbox** Library with Navigation UI as follow.

```
implementation "com.mapbox.navigation:ui:1.5.1"
implementation 'com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-sdk:9.6.1'
```

Link of documentation:

- [Navigation SDK](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/)
- [Map SDK](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/)

What I have implemented:

XML:

```
<com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/navigationView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/ll_nav"
    mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="15" />
```

and Output is:

[image]

**I want that MAP in DARK Mode with Red color of Route Direction.** I tried many solutions of older library versions but I didn't found any clue for newer one. I have also tried to implement [Style](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/styles/) but not working for **NavigationView**.

Can anyone please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should checkout this [navigation style and guide link](https://docs.mapbox.com/android/navigation/guides/styles/) to customise it using Android standard way of style. (Same link you shared in your question. You just need to use their provided `app:navigationDarkTheme` attributes and inherit their default style.

```
<com.mapbox.navigation.ui.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navigationView"
        app:navigationDarkTheme="@style/CustomNavigationViewDark"
        app:navigationLightTheme="@style/CustomNavigationViewDark"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/ll_nav"
        mapbox:mapbox_cameraZoom="15" />
```

CustomNavigationViewDark:

```
<style name="CustomNavigationViewDark" parent="MapboxStyleNavigationViewDark">
        <!-- The main turn banner view at the top of the screen -->
        <!-- Background color of the banner -->
        <item name="navigationViewBannerBackground">#FFFFFF</item>
        <!-- Color for the primary label that displays the turn name -->
        <item name="navigationViewBannerPrimaryText">#37516F</item>
        <!-- Color for the secondary label that occasionally appears underneath the primary label -->
        <item name="navigationViewBannerSecondaryText">#E637516F</item>
        <!-- Primary color for the turn arrow icons-->
        <item name="navigationViewBannerManeuverPrimary">#37516F</item>
        <!-- Secondary color for the turn arrow icons (e.g. the line segment that forks off) -->
        <item name="navigationViewBannerManeuverSecondary">#4D37516F</item>
        <!-- Alternate background color for the dropdown list of upcoming steps -->
        <item name="navigationViewListBackground">#FAFAFA</item>

        <!-- The summary view along the bottom of the screen -->
        <!-- Background color of the summary view -->
        <item name="navigationViewPrimary">@color/mapboxWhite</item>
        <!-- Tint color for icons in the summary view -->
        <item name="navigationViewSecondary">@color/mapboxBlue</item>
        <!-- Accent color for elements such as the recenter button -->
        <item name="navigationViewAccent">@color/mapboxPink</item>
        <!-- Color for the main duration label in the summary view -->
        <item name="navigationViewPrimaryText">#424242</item>
        <!-- Color for the secondary distance and ETA label in the summary view -->
        <item name="navigationViewSecondaryText">#424242</item>

        <!-- Custom colors for progress bars displayed during navigation -->
        <item name="navigationViewProgress">@color/red</item>
        <item name="navigationViewProgressBackground">@color/red</item>

        <!-- Custom colors for the route line and traffic -->
        <item name="navigationViewRouteStyle">@style/CustomNavigationMapRoute</item>

        <!-- Map style -->
        <item name="navigationViewMapStyle">mapbox://styles/bipinnt/ckp9cn6f10zyk17pk5gnxpelu</item>

        <!-- Other components -->
<!--        <item name="navigationViewDivider">#4882C6</item>-->
<!--        <item name="navigationViewRouteOverviewDrawable">#FAFAFA</item>-->
<!--        <item name="navigationViewDestinationMarker">@drawable/map_marker_light</item>-->
<!--        <item name="navigationViewLocationLayerStyle">@style/NavigationLocationLayerStyle</item>-->
    </style>
```

I hope this will resolve your issue/queries related to customisation of NavigationView.